# How to save the random variable so that I can use it for POST and GET

Tags: python, flask, http-post, http-get

Im currently taking the cs50 course and for my final project I wanted to create a simple application in which a random word from a sqlite db gets picked and than the user should input the same word as displayed.

Now I have a problem which Im not able to fix. When a user gets on the site I want to display the random word and when the user wants to correct the inputed word it should direct him to a new html file to "correct" the word and then redirect him to the mainpage.

Now Im not able to do that because when a user "submits" the word via POST a new random number gets generated and with that the words displayed are different and will never be the same. And I cant figure out how to fix it.

Please help thx.

my current code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def mainpage():

    for i in range(1):
        randoms = random.randrange(1,10)

    words = db.execute("SELECT WORD FROM words WHERE ID = ?", randoms)

    word = str(words)

    if request.method == "POST":

        return render_template("check.html", counter=counter, input=input, word=word, random=randoms)

    return render_template("mainpage.html", word=word, random=randoms)
```

I tried reading the words into a txt file and than read the word from the file into the programm but the displayed words are still different because a new random number is generated as im going down the POST route.

EDIT:

I have found a way to do it with the help of chatgpt (lol), the counter resets to 1 if it hits 10:

> @app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
> def mainpage():
> if 'counter' not in session:
> session['counter'] = 1  # Initialize the counter if it doesn't exist in the session

```
return render_template("mainpage.html")
```

@app.route("/start", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def start():
if 'counter' not in session:
session['counter'] = 1  # Initialize the counter if it doesn't exist in the session

```
result = db.execute("SELECT WORD FROM words WHERE ID = ?", session['counter'])
words = result[0]['WORD']
word = str(words)

if request.method == "POST":
    input = request.form.get("input")

    if word == input:
        session['counter'] += 1

        if session['counter'] > 10:
            session['counter'] = 1  # Reset the counter when it reaches 10

        return render_template("check.html")
    else:
        return render_template("wrong.html")

return render_template("start.html", word=word)
```